# "Like" a picture with Facebook SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

Hi guys I'm trying to "like" a picture with Facebook SDK for iOS, I searched on the web but I don't understand how to implement it, I tried:

```
[[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes", idPicture] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
         startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           id result,
           NSError *error) {
             if(!error) {

             }
         }];
```

But it doesn't work, do you know some other method? :)

Comment: What are the values of `result` and `error` when you make this call?

Comment: error is nil, result has no element

Comment: No wait! This code works ahahah Yeah I know, I'm stupid

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Before like a picture, make sure that the user have signed in to facebook and you have offline access on behalf of that user. Follow the official detailed documented stuff here to authenticate user before liking any stuff:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/